# How do I omit labels in the R treemap?

Tags: r, treemap

I've been using the [R treemap package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/treemap/treemap.pdf) and I have a treemap that's 2 levels deep. I want the second level labels to be printed but not the first.

Using the example in the man page:

```
tmPlot(GNI2010,
       index=c("continent", "iso3"),
       vSize="population",
       vColor="GNI",
       type="value")
```

[treemap example http://www.eecs.tufts.edu/~rveroy/stuff/GNI2010-treemap.png](http://www.eecs.tufts.edu/~rveroy/stuff/GNI2010-treemap.png)

I want to get rid of the continent labels, but retain the iso3 labels. I apologize in advance if it is in the documents but haven't found it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove the continent labels, you can post hoc edit the graph. The graph produces a grid object. The last two elements of this grid object seem to be the country labels. Hence you can remove them this way:

```
lapply(tail(grid.ls(print=FALSE)$name, 2), grid.remove)
```

[image]

Comment: I don't want the continent label but I still want to aggregate based on continent. I want the layout as I have it, but without the continent labels.

Answer (score 7):

Another option would consist in nullifying the size font the fonts you want to see disappear. For instance,

```
tmPlot(GNI2010,
       index=c("continent", "iso3"),
       vSize="population",
       vColor="GNI",
       type="value",
       fontsize.labels=c(0,10))
```

will only display the initial for the countries, not for the continents.