# R Tree-maps - make label background transparent

Tags: r, treemap

I'm trying to create a treemap using R package `treemap`. Here is the code (it's a sample from the package)

```
library(treemap)
data(GNI2010)
treemap(GNI2010,
        index=c("continent", "iso3"),
        vSize="population",
        vColor="GNI",
        type="value")
```

The issue I'm having is with the colour of the labels. When I have just one index, then the output is ok:

```
library(treemap)
    data(GNI2010)
    treemap(GNI2010,
            index=c("iso3"), #single index
            vSize="population",
            vColor="GNI",
            type="value")
```

[image]

But when I have multiple indexes, then the label changes colour. I just want all labels to be transparent. Is that possible?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just as I wrote this I found the solution in the documentation:
you just need to add the option `bg.lables = 0`. Its a range from 0-255, by default its 220.

```
library(treemap)
data(GNI2010)
treemap(GNI2010,
        index=c("continent", "iso3"),
        vSize="population",
        vColor="GNI",
        type="value",
        bg.labels = 0)
```

[image]

There are other options in the package to let you play with colours. But at least the label can be transparent.

Answer (score 0):

Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950967/how-do-i-omit-labels-in-the-r-treemap):

To remove the continent labels, you can post hoc edit the graph. The graph produces a grid object. The last two elements of this grid object seem to be the country labels. Hence you can remove them this way:

```
lapply(tail(grid.ls(print=FALSE)$name, 2), grid.remove)
```

Comment: grid.remove is not working. I think this code refers to tmPlot which seems to be an older version of treemap.